# How to upload a large number of objects to a storage bucket

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I want to write a large number of objects to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. I am performing these writes in parallel in batches of 50 with a 1 second delay between writing each batch.

Here's my code.

```
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");

const keyFilename = "path/to/service/account/file";
const projectId = "projectId";
const googleCloudConfig = { projectId, keyFilename };
const storage = new Storage(googleCloudConfig);
const bucket = storage.bucket("bucketName");

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const writeDocs = async () => {
  try {
    const arr = new Array(1000).fill({ test: "test"});
    const promises = [];
    for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const file = bucket.file(`test/${i}.json`);
      promises.push(file.save(JSON.stringify(arr[i]), () => console.log(`saved JSON document ${i} to storage`)));

      if (promises.length >= 50) {
        console.log("writing batch. total:", i+1)
        await Promise.all(promises);
        promises.length = 0;
        await sleep(1000);
      }
    }

    if (promises.length) {
      await Promise.all(promises);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

writeDocs();
```

I expect to have 1000 objects in the `test/` directory in my bucket at the end of this script but only have 400. Why is this? Are there any undocumented rate limits that are relevant here?

EDIT: I have edited my question to just include a minimal example demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have included the code that performs the writes to Google Cloud Storage. I am essentially making many parallel calls to file.save() from https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save

Comment: When you specify a callback to save, it doesn't return a promise.  Your code is awaiting nothing and probably terminating before all the work is complete. If you want a promise, don't use a callback. https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest/storage/file#_google_cloud_storage_File_save_member_2_

Comment: @DougStevenson after removing the callback I am now seeing that there are in fact promise rejections after around 400 writes. The error code is `ECONNREFUSED` which is thrown by `node-fetch` which seems to be the library that the Cloud Storage NodeJS client uses under the hood. This leads me to think that the Google Cloud Storage API rejects connections after around 400 requests. Is there any way I can confirm this and potentially get around it?